# RedCloth and Ruby string interpolation possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, redcloth

I have a view which renders a block of text through RedCloth and I would want to add some variables to that text, f.ex. through ruby string interpolation.

Is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you use redcloth, so your users/editors will enter text, but they will be given a few keywords they can enter and which will be filled in at render time. For example something like `author, date, ...` but of course I have no idea what your website is for.

The cleanest *delayed* string interpolation is to use the `%` operator.

Some nonsense example for demonstration purposes only :

```
some_text = "flap %{cookie} some more %{action} NOW!" 
filled_in_text = some_text % {cookie: 'banana', action: 'eating' }
Redcloth.new(filled_in_text).to_html
```

So you will retrieve `some_text` from the database (model), what the user/editor typed, and then interpolate using the `%` and a hash of possible (supported values). The result you just hand to redcloth.